# Regex to find 5 integers before last underscore of filename

Tags: regex

I need to find 5 integers before the last underscore in a given filename.

Example string:

```
X130874_W907025343_Txt.pdf
```

I need to find `25353`

The closest I came was `(?<=_)[^_]+(?=[^_](.{5})_)`

Comment: You won't find that string in that pdf name

Comment: Could the file name be `'X130874_W907025343Cat_Txt.pdf'` and you want to extract `'25343'`; that is, must the last underscore immediately follow the five digits of interest? Could the file name be `X130874_W907025343_A21_Txt.pdf'` and you want to extract the same `'25343'`; that is, the last five digits before the last underscore?  That's the problem with asking a question in terms of a single example. Incidentally, it would be clearer to refer to "five digits" than "five integers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead after 5 digits that matches an underscore followed by no undercores until the end.

```
\d{5}(?=_[^_]*$)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```php
[0-9]{5}(?=_(?!.*_))
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/5L9ptL/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{5}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (5 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```